# Extracting the basename from a filepath argument

Tags: macros

I have a function which takes a *filepath* as an argument. How can I extract the *basename* (`file.c` in the example below) from the argument?

```
\mycommand{path/to/file.c}

...

\def\@mycommand#1{
  ...
  \section{\basename{#1})}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTeX includes a filepath parser (the exact syntax it parses depends on the system)

```
\makeatletter

\filename@parse{path/to/file.c}

\typeout{area: \filename@area}

\typeout{name: \filename@base}

\typeout{ext: \filename@ext}

\makeatother
```

Produces this on the terminal:

```
area: path/to/
name: file
ext: c
```