# Filename in line 0 of a lstlisting

Tags: listings, counters

I'm trying to write a lstlisting-environment which sets the filename as line 0. I tryed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{numbers=left}

% @param 1 : filename
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1]{\setcounter{lstlisting}{0}, #1}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{code}[main.cpp]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::cout

int main(void){
    cout << "Hello World";
}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Should it look like `\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=0]
         main.cpp`? Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: *[...] sets the filename as line 0.* What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Jubobs, I believe what OP means is that in their example, the result would be like "0. main.cpp <newline> 1. #include <iostream> etc".

Comment: @Pouya You may be right :) but I don't think that's such a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Think twice

Are you suggesting inserting the filename at the top of your listing, on a line numbered by 0, as if it were a line of code? I think that's a bad idea: you run the risk of confusing your readers.

## Typeset the filename as the listing's title

A better alternative, in my opinion, is to typeset the filename as the listing's title, by passing the parameter to the `title` key; see below.

[image]

Besides, in your example, you define your `code` environment so that it accept a mandatory parameter, but you use it as if it accepted an optional one; that's not right. Anyway, a better approach is to allow for an optional argument alongside the mandatory one, so you can still pass options to the underlying `listings` environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{%
  \lstset{%
    numbers = left,
    title   = #2,
    #1,
  }%
}{}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[2][]{%
  \lstset{%
    numbers = left,
    title   = #2,
    #1,
  }%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}{main.cpp}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::cout

int main(void){
    cout << "Hello World";
}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

---

## External listings: how to programmatically use the filename as title

(See [daleif's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261748/filename-in-line-0-of-a-lstlisting/262294?noredirect=1#comment629031_262294))

If you're inserting an external file with `\lstinputlisting` and want to programmatically typeset the relative path to that file, or just its filename, as title of that listing, you can do as in the following example.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- to correctly print underscores
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% assuming folder "./foo" exists...
\begin{filecontents*}{foo/my_main_program.cpp}
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::cout

int main(void){
    cout << "Hello World";
}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\inputcode[2][]{%
  \filename@parse{\detokenize{#2}}
  \lstinputlisting[%
    numbers = left,
    % title   = \lstname,                    % <-- relative path
    title   = \filename@base.\filename@ext,  % <-- only the filename
    #1,
  ]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inputcode{foo/my_main_program.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if `main.cpp` is an external file. Can `\lstinputlisting` be *hacked* such that it automatically adds the filename as the title? Then one does not have to type this twice, and thus reduces human error

Comment: @daleif Sure; see my edit.

Comment: Where does `\filename@parse` and friends come from? The kernel?

Comment: @daleif Yes; see [this answer by David](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65345/extracting-the-basename-from-a-filepath-argument). I'm not sure whether `\filename@parse` is very portable.

Comment: BTW: your example fails if there is, say, a `_` in the file name.

Comment: @daleif Yes; I hadn't thought about that :)

Comment: Quite common in file names. If er do not parse it, use can cimply use `\path{#1}` with `\path` from `url`.

Comment: @daleif See my last edit. Using `detokenize` was enough to fix the underscore problem.